# How to handle social login with Facebook for multiple domain without white list each and every domain in the Facebook app

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, angular-social-login

I’m currently setting up a Facebook app to enable Facebook login for my angular application. we have multiple tenants of the same app deployed at different domain name.I was wondering whether it is possible to support all the tenants under a single Facebook app, is there any way to do that without adding my multiple domain details in Facebook app.?

Comment: No, that is not possible. (And I am not sure if it is possible by just adding additional domains either, I think they might need to belong to the same business these days or something like that.)

Comment: ok, i just wanted to confirm there is no such thing is there to do that task. Thanks for the quick response @CBroe.

Comment: Also it would be great if you can suggest any way to achieve this, like using another project only for handling social login and get the redirection from that project to my multiple tenants. Is that possible? appreciate any small help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also it would be great if you can suggest any way to achieve this, like using another project only for handling social login and get the redirection from that project to my multiple tenants.

That would be an option, yes.

If you want to use the client-side login flow that is based on the JS SDK, then you will have to send users to your domain first, because the SDK will only properly initialize on a valid app domain.

With the server-side flow, you could handle the whole thing mostly transparently for users. You can start the process from the tenant’s domain, specify your own domain in the redirect_uri parameter. When the user lands there, exchange the code for a token, and then pass that back when you redirect back to the tenant’s domain.